# Parallel For to sum an array of ushorts (big array 18M)

Tags: c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I would like to use parallel processing for taking array statistics for large arrays of unsigned short (16 bit) values.

ushort[] array = new ushort[2560 * 3072]; // x = rows(2560) y = columns(3072)

double avg = Parallel.For (0, array.Length, WHAT GOES HERE);

The same for standard deviation & standard deviation of row means.

I have normal for loop versions of these functions and they take too long when combined with Median Filter methods.

The end product is to try and get a Median Filter for the array. But the first steps are important as well. So if you have the whole solution great but if you want to help with the first parts as well it is all appreciated.

Comment: Is there any way to leverage the pre-defined int functions for ushorts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried PLINQ?

```
double average = array.AsParallel().Average(n => n);
```

I'm not sure how performant it will be with a large array of `ushort` values, but it's worth testing to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: +1 works perfectly. I didn't notice the average as double for array of ushorts. Had to use double after testing. +1 for that too.